# Robolectric and Powermock attempting to mock static method, y u no work?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 2.1, Powermock 1.5.1 and i would like to simply write a static method test. i just want to verify that a static method of a class is NEVER called when passing in false as an argument:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyStaticClassToTest.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void staticMethod_shouldNeverBeCalled() throws Exception {
        MyStaticClassToTest instance = new MyStaticClassToTest();

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyStaticClassToTest.class);
        PowerMockito.when(MyStaticClassToTest.staticMethod(new Context)).thenReturn("wtf?");

        instance.iCallStaticMethod(false);

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1)); //i want this to fail, but it keeps passing
        MyStaticClassToTest.staticMethod(context);
    }
}
```

Where i have a class defined like:

```
public class MyStaticClassToTest {
    public void iCallStaticMethod(boolean yesOrNo){
        if(yesOrNo) staticMethod(new Context());
    }
    public static String staticMethod(Context androidContext){
        //do something... 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why is that my test keeps passing? I want it to verify that the static method is NEVER called.

Comment: *"y u no work?"*  Why you no spell words properly?

Comment: Both frameworks use class loader customisation. So I'm not sure if they could be used simultaneously. Wrap you static call in some class and mock it with mockito. Or re-define all Android API calls with powermock.

Comment: Can you post your EXACT code please?  Rather than re-typing it?  You may have made some errors in your re-typing.  The excerpt above has a syntax error, so you can't have copy/pasted it from your actual code.

Comment: How did you even get this to run?

Comment: @C.Ross what's your setup like? PowerMock has to be above a certain version (i believe 1.4 or higher?)

Comment: it does not seem to me that Robolectric is used in this case.  also, I have problems verifying if a static method was called if it was called from another static method.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443276/verify-a-static-method-was-called-by-another-static-method-in-powermock